# S3 golang Multipart upload using Presigned url

Tags: go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

We are writing an application in "go" language where I generate a Presigned url from my service (using PutObjectRequest() and Presign()) and pass it to an external service so that the external service can perform the multipart upload of larger files to S3 (using presigned url). We do not want to give the AWS credentials to the external service, that is why we plan to provide a presigned url. Also, since the files are large we need to use the multipart upload feature provided by AWS SDK.

I did a quick search and could not find any functions that do this in the aws sdk. 
Does the AWS sdk for go language support multipart upload using presigned url? Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure if any of the official SDKs support this out of the box but according to [this discussion](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/468) it's possible to implement.

Comment: It's possible if the external service supports it. I do it with EvaporateJS, for each part it sends a request to my service where I sign it, and return it to the external service so it can upload the part. EvaporateJS is open source so you can take a look at how it's implemented and in the Go example you can see how to sign the request.

Comment: In my case, the external service is also an application written in golang.

Comment: If you familiarize yourself with the multipart API, you'll see the problem.  A multipart upload requires at least *n* + 2 unique signed URLs, one for each of *n* parts, one to start and one to complete the multipart operation, and each of these needs to be generated as the process is ongoing.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the inputs. I am also trying to explore if I can achieve the multiple part upload or streaming behavior to upload the files to S3 using any of the other options like http or anything else?  Someone suggested me  (https://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2013/07/01/golang-multipart-file-upload-example/ , but this doesn't seem to work to upload files to S3. Are you aware of any similar mechanism that can work to upload files to S3?

Comment: Can we upload larger files to S3 using http POST without copying the entire file to memory (using golang)? I tried using the bufio.NewReader as the reader argument for http.NewRequest() but that doesn't seem to work. I am new to golang and S3, so trying to find the right solution for this. Please let me know your thoughts. ` rdr := bufio.NewReader(file) requ, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", urlStr,rdr) if err != nil { fmt.Println("error creating request", urlStr) return } `

Answer (score 1):

Create the request to Amazon to get an UploadID for multipart, create several parts from it and pre-sign each normally.  Send these to the client to use them.

```golang
func (s *s3) UploadMultipartPresignedCreate(key string) ([]string) {
  // Query with bucket and key to fetch UploadID
    out, err := s.s3.CreateMultipartUploadRequest(&s3.CreateMultipartUploadInput{
        Bucket: &s.bucketName,
        Key:    aws.String(key),
    })

    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }

  // Generate parts
    var parts = 10 // Number of parts
    requests := make([]string, 0, parts)

    for i := 0; i < parts; i++ {
        req, _ := i.s3.UploadPartRequest(&s3.UploadPartInput{
            Bucket:     &s.bucketName,
            Key:        aws.String(key),
            PartNumber: aws.Int64((int64)(i)),
            UploadId:   out.UploadId,
        })

    // Presign each time with whatever expiration time you want
        url, err := req.Presign(time.Hour)

        if err != nil {
            return nil
        }

        requests = append(requests, url)
    }

  // Returning a list of presigned URLs
    return requests, nil
}
```

At this point the client should succeed or fail their upload and ping you back with completion of process (on a separate endpoint, typically).  At this point you'll want to carry out the Upload completion.

```golang
func (s *S3) UploadMultipartComplete(key string, uploadId string) (string) {
    out, err := s.s3.CompleteMultipartUpload(&s3.CompleteMultipartUploadInput{
        Bucket:   &s.bucketName,
        Key:      aws.String(key),
        UploadId: aws.String(uploadId),
    })

    if err != nil {
        return "" // Give a reasonable error
    }

    return *out.Key, nil
}
```

If the client informs you that for whatever reason (possibly expiry, or change of mind) the multipart upload has failed, you can instead abort the multipart (and you should, since you'll be charged until it expires).  This would be done in place of the `CompleteMultipartUpload` above.

```golang
out, err := i.s3.AbortMultipartUpload(&s3.AbortMultipartUploadInput{
    Bucket:   &i.bucketName,
    Key:      aws.String(key),
    UploadId: aws.String(uploadId),
})
```

Answer (score -1):

The AWS Go SDK documentation provides a spelled out example of using presigned PUT URLs for uploading: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-presigned-urls.html

For example (copied relevant part from the documentation)

```
    // Create S3 service client
    svc := s3.New(sess)

    resp, _ := svc.PutObjectRequest(&s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("testBucket"),
        Key:    aws.String("testKey"),
    })

    md5s := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
    resp.HTTPRequest.Header.Set("Content-MD5", md5s)

    url, err := resp.Presign(15 * time.Minute)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error presigning request", err)
        return
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", url, strings.NewReader(""))
    req.Header.Set("Content-MD5", md5s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error creating request", url)
        return
    }
```

Comment: This is not what the user asked.  There's is no mention of Multipart Uploads being utilised in this case.